# Уточнения кода Голея

Tags: алгоритм

Добрый день вопрос, нужно реализовать кодирование и декодирование кода Голея. Есть пару вопросов:
1) Допустим я ввёл строку "*то1*", в коде Хэминга нужно брать по два символа и добавлять контрольные биты. Но как быть в моём случаем кодировать по одному символу, добавляя не 11, а 15 нулей? Т. е. представляю символы в двоичном виде аски кодов (**т** = 11110010) (**о** = 11101110), (**1** = 11111)
И начинаю кодировать, поочерёдно каждый символ: Но чтобы, начать кодировать мне нужно символ до 12 знаков дополнить, но как спереди нулей написать или сзади?

Просто на сайте на котором смотрю алгоритм они вообще число инвертируют (сайт в конце скину и скрин)

2) Нужно делать "исключающее или" в алгоритме написано 11 раз, но на том же сайте делают 5, а в коде вообще 12 @_@

Было бы здорово, если кто-нибудь попунктно расписал алгоритм кодирования и декодирования, на том же примере "то1", а то я только запутался.
Спасибо.
www.aqdi.com/golay.htm
[image: Пример]